# Howto reduce startup warnings

Tags: .net, ignite

The following default configuration creates a bunch of warnings? How can they be reduced?

```
config = new IgniteConfiguration()
{
    Logger = new Apache.Ignite.Log4Net.IgniteLog4NetLogger(),
};
this.ignite = Ignition.Start(config);
```

List of warnings

1. GC server mode is not enabled, this could lead to less than optimal performance on multi-core machines (to enable see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Initial heap size is 124MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
3. Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
4. Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
5. Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
6. Marshaller is automatically set to o.a.i.i.binary.BinaryMarshaller (other nodes must have the same marshaller type).
7. TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder has no pre-configured addresses (it is recommended in production to specify at least one address in TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder.getAddresses() configuration property)

Solution to 1: Add to app.config

```
<runtime>
  <gcServer enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

Solution to 2:

```
// Xms512m -> 512 MB min usage
// Xmx2g   -> 2 GB max usage
config.JvmOptions = new List<string> { "-Xms512m", "-Xmx2g" };
```

Solution to 3:

```
config.CommunicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi
{
    MessageQueueLimit = 1024, // It seem that 1024 is supposed to be the default value
};
```

Solution to 7:

```
config.DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
{
    IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder
    {
        Endpoints = new List<string> { "127.0.0.1" }
    }
};
```

Comment: solution to 3, 7:             var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
            {
                DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
                {
                    IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder {Endpoints = new List<string> {"127.0.0.1"}}
                },
                JvmOptions =new List<string> { "-Xms2g", "-Xmx2g"},
            };

Comment: There are still two warnings that raise my concern "Checkpoints are disabled" and "Collision resolution is disabled". Any ideas?

Comment: Checkpoints are disabled: you see this warning because by default Ignite used NoopCheckpointSpi (that is a stub implementation). Ignite provides several implementations:

https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/checkpoint/CheckpointSpi.html

Next should help:
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
 // Override default checkpoint SPI.
 cfg.setCheckpointSpi(cpSpi);

Comment: Collision resolution is disabled: Collision SPI allows to regulate how grid jobs get executed when they arrive on a destination node. By default NoopCollisionSpi is used. Please take a look here: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/collision/CollisionSpi.html To fix this warning please do next:  IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

 // Override default collision SPI.
 cfg.setCollisionSpi(colSpi);

Comment: Unfortunately both ( cfg.setCheckpointSpi(cpSpi) and cfg.setCollisionSpi(colSpi) ) are not available in the .NET API of version 2.4. At least I do not find it..

Comment: Oh I see.  Do you try to configurate it using https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/configuration#section-spring-xml